# Blazor 8 InteractiveAuto mode app: server-only configuration

Tags: blazor

In a Blazor Web App 8 with InteractiveAuto mode enabled, is it possible to have server-only configuration, that is not accessible by components defined in the client project?

The Blazor Web App template with InteractiveAuto global rendering mode creates two projects: BlazorWebApp and BlazorWebApp.Client. If I define a setting in the BlazorWebApp appsettings.json (or in user secrets or through environment variables), then this setting is visible in the BlazorWebApp.Client components through IConfiguration injection. However, if the majority of the app is SSR and the few interactive components don't need API, then it would make sense to access database directly from the server-side project through a connection string. But I think this connection string should not be visible to code that runs on the client.

Comment: Only the *appsettings.json* in the *BlazorWebApp.Client* project is available to the WASM client - it's in the *wwwroot* folder.  *BlazorWebApp* in the server project is server only: it's in the root project folder.